# Letters Missing parts with OpenALPR PrepCharsForTraining Utility

Tags: ocr, tesseract, openalpr

I did run `openalpr-utils-prepcharsfortraining` on numbers and arabic letters, but the dots are cropped out... You can see the result in my output tiff (converted to png).

The images were resized to get max height 40px.

[characters tiff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SbJg.png)

Here is the original ب but the dot below was removed in the `tiff` format:

[ب](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXPcK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed, just edit the code in [this file](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/blob/master/src/misc_utilities/prepcharsfortraining.cpp):

`float minHeightPercent = 0.0;`

That's it!